# How to map dropdown from Spring form to one to many entities?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-form

I have two entities like below, and in my JSP page the drop down code is written, and i'm unable to map fields from Spring form to `SecondarySkill` through `OneToMany` scenario.

Please suggest how could i map the below drop down to `SecondarySkill` entity skill name.

**java code:**

```
public class Requisition {
    //some fields
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="req")   
    private Set<SecondarySkill> secSkill;

    //setters and getters
}

public class SecondarySkill{

    private int id;
    private String skillName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="req_id")
    Requisition req;

    //setters and getters
}
```

**JSP code:**

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Secondary Skill:
<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
<form:select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" path="rpd" id="secSkillId">                                                 

    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">JAVA</option>
    <option value="2">.Net</option>
    <option value="3">PHP</option>

</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form:options` to populate your options collection.

```
<form:select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" path="rpd" id="secSkillId">                                                     
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <form:options items="${secSkill}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="skillName"/>    
</form:select>
```

Comment: did  you try this solution?